# Creating context menu for win32 API

Tags: winapi, contextmenu

I am trying to create context menu for win32 application using

```
case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
{
    HMENU hPopupMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
    InsertMenu(hPopupMenu, 0, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_STRING, ID_CLOSE, (LPCWSTR)"Exit");
    InsertMenu(hPopupMenu, 0, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_STRING, ID_EXIT, (LPCWSTR)"Play");
    SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
    TrackPopupMenu(hPopupMenu, TPM_BOTTOMALIGN | TPM_LEFTALIGN, 0, 0, 0, hWnd, NULL);
}
```

But I always get context menu as shown below

[alt text http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/866/70219076.png](http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/866/70219076.png)

I want text **exit** and **play** to be displayed in the menu

Comment: I guess the image is totally lost now.  So glad that SO now allows pasting images.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't convert a string literal to wide by casting, you have to declare it as a wide char string. The casting just defeats the compiler warning, it doesn't change the content of the string.

change this

```
(LPCWSTR)"Exit"
(LPCWSTR)"Play"
```

to this

```
_T("Exit")
_T("Play")
```

or this

```
L"Exit"
L"Play"
```

Answer (score 2):

Following worked for me

```
case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
          {
            HMENU hPopupMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
            InsertMenu(hPopupMenu, 0, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_STRING, ID_CLOSE, L"Exit");
            InsertMenu(hPopupMenu, 0, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_STRING, ID_EXIT, L"Play");
            SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
            TrackPopupMenu(hPopupMenu, TPM_BOTTOMALIGN | TPM_LEFTALIGN, 0, 0, 0, hWnd, NULL);
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you specifying the encoding in the API function definition?  I ran into that problem recently and removing the specification fixed the problem.